# Play on steam don't function

Tags: steam

I installed the Hitman Absolution, but when I try to run the game
it starts and soon closes without showing any error message

I use a notebook lenovo, with 500 GB of HD, video card Intel hd Graphics 520 and 4 GB of RAM

Comment: According to the minimum requirements, for this game to work, you're gonna need a dedicated video card `Nvidia 8600 512 MB, or AMD equivalent`, source: https://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/hitman-absolution

Comment: Intel HD Graphics isn't going to be sufficient to run much under Steam Play.  This is partly due to the game sysreqs but also Steam Play still taking a ton of resources.